# How can I add log messages to an NUnit test that will appear in a nant build execution?

Tags: logging, nunit, nant

With NUnit, if you add Debug.Print statements in your tests they appear in the test output. (At least they do in the ReSharper unit test window.)

When using a NAnt build file that executes the same tests, those Debug.Print statements do not appear.

How can I add messages to my unit tests that will appear both in the NUnit output and the build log output from NAnt?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` should be preserved (it is for my version of NUnit at least).

That said, consider - each time you want to add some text output - how you could turn it into an assertion with a message. Your tests will get much better.

Comment: Generally I would agree with you, but in this case the information needed wasn't related to testing the app, it was metadata related to running the tests (specifically the executing path).

Comment: Using Resharper + NUnit 2 you occasionally get interleaved results, or missing text at the end.

Answer (score 67):

NUnit 3's way of logging during a test is via the `TestContext` class. It has a raft of static Write variants. Each emits general content to the test result.

`TestContext.Out` yields a `TextWriter` that can also be used to emit logging information into test results.

Comment: Is there a solution for NUnit 2?

Comment: Is this any different from calling `Console.WriteLine()`? Does the message get embedded in the test result? Sorry for the lazy asking -- trying to build a testrunner with NUnit.Engine and wondering if I can capture notes like these within the output XML. I will experiment.